# Hiding an #include used by template class from users of the class

Tags: c++, templates, include, information-hiding

Consider the following code spread out along 3 files:

```
// secret.h
#pragma once
class Secret { /* ... */ };

// foo.h
#pragma once
#include "secret.h"
template <typename T>
class Foo {
public:
    // Other members ...
    void bar();
};

/* Definition is included inside 'foo.h' because Foo is a template class. */
template <typename T> void Foo<T>::bar() {
    Secret s;
    /* Perform stuff that depend on 'secret.h' ... */
}

// main.cpp
#include "foo.h"
int main() {
    Foo<int> foo;
    Secret secret; // <--- This shouldn't be allowed, but it is!
    return 0;
}
```

So my issue is that I want to hide **Secret** from the user of **Foo** *unless* they explicitly use `#include "secret.h"`. Normally, this would be done by including `secret.h` in `foo.cpp`. However, this isn't possible because **Foo** is a template class and I cannot separate its definition from its declaration. [Explicit template instantiation](http://www.cplusplus.com/articles/1C75fSEw/) is not an option.

Ultimately, I want to know if this is possible in some way other than Explicit template instantiation, and if so, how? Thanks!

Comment: can `Secret` friend `Foo`?  Or is it viable to hide Secret behind a non-template thin wrapper?

Comment: @MooingDuck: This is certainly a possibility, to put Secret in a thin wrapper. You should've put this as an answer! I never thought of that. :P

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So thanks to @Mooing Duck's hint, I think I got the answer. They way I'm considering solving this by creating a new class that acts as a thin wrapper for **Secret** that does not rely on a template parameter. This class would friend **Foo** and provide protected access to **Secret**, thus allowing **Foo** to access **Secret** without exposing **Secret** to the public user through inclusion of `"foo.h"`.

I will update this answer with the actual code snippet once I write and compile it and make sure that it works.

Comment: Heh, It was so easy a solution that I assumed it wouldn't work for you particular case for some reason

Comment: @Mooing Duck, Yah, for some reason it didn't occur to me at all. Thanks. :)

Comment: You never updated, the suspense of what happened next is killing me  internally

Answer (score 1):

That is not possible with all those conditions which you mentioned, because writing  `#include "foo.h"` means you also implictly write `#include "secret.h"` (means, all it contents).

You can use namespace such as `details` to limit the visibility of the name of the class:

```
// secret.h
#pragma once

namespace details
{
   class Secret { /* ... */ };
}
```

And then write `details::Secret` wherever you use it.

DO NOT write `using namespace details;`, NOT even `using details::Secret;`.

Comment: Can't they simply do `int main() {details::Secret;}` then?

Comment: @MooingDuck: They can. I'm hoping to avoid that as well. In fact, in the actual solution, **Secret** is already in a namespace. I just want the namespace to be hidden as well.

Comment: @teedayf: why? what are you trying to achieve by hiding that header? (Compilation speed? Protecting business secrets? Something else?)

Comment: @jalf: It falls under the whole "separation of concerns" and "information hiding" and all that in terms of the design. There is no other functional reason. If it's possible, it'd make the design better, so it's not a strict constraint. Granted, I think Mooing Duck gave me the idea I was looking for in the comments of the OP.